# pgbouncer routing rules not selecting correct authenticated connection pool

Tags: pgbouncer

I'm testing pgbouncer for a usecase I have. I want to use the routing_rules feature, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I hope I'm missing something obvious. I'm running everything in a docker compose with pgbouncer on port 5435 and two postgres db's, postgres1 and postgres2

I have the following databases configured:

```
[databases]
    incoming = host=postgres1 port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres
    postgres1 = host=postgres1 port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres
    postgres2 = host=postgres2 port=5432 user=postgres2 password=postgres2 dbname=postgres
```

I have the following script location:

```
[pgbouncer]
    ...
    routing_rules_py_module_file = /home/pgbouncer/routing_rules.py
    ...
```

I'm fairly certain this works, because when I connect from my Spring Boot application to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/incoming or jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/postgres1 or jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/postgres2 everything works as expected, as long as my routing_rules implementation returns None:

```
def routing_rules(username, query, in_transaction):
    return None
```

if I change this to return a db_key, for example:

```
def routing_rules(username, query, in_transaction):
    return "postgres1"
```

and connect to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/incoming

I get the following lines in my log file. It seems pgbouncer tries to connect with wrong credentials? Any help is appreciated!

```
pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.247 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 P: got connection: 192.168.65.1:56405 -> 192.168.65.1:5432

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.253 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 got var: user=admin

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.253 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 got var: database=incoming

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.253 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 got var: client_encoding=UTF8

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.253 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 got var: DateStyle=ISO

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.253 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 got var: TimeZone=Europe/Amsterdam

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.254 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: (nodb)/(nouser)@192.168.65.1:56405 ignoring startup parameter: extra_float_digits=2

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.254 UTC [12] LOG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 login attempt: db=incoming user=admin tls=no

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.255 UTC [12] DEBUG finish_client_login: not using fast switchovers

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.255 UTC [12] DEBUG finish_client_login: no welcome message, pause

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.255 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 pause_client

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.256 UTC [12] DEBUG zone_register(postgres1)

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.256 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 4, for: incoming

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.256 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.256 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.256 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@(bad-af):0 dns_callback: inet4: 172.21.0.3:5432

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.256 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 launching new connection to server

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 4, for: incoming

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: connect ok

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] LOG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 new connection to server (from 172.21.0.4:40532)

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG pktbuf_dynamic(512): 0x381abfd0

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 4, for: incoming

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.257 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.268 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 calling login_answer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.269 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: req md5-crypted psw

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.269 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 P: send md5 password

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.269 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 4, for: incoming

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.269 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.269 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 4, for: incoming

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 calling login_answer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: auth ok

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: application_name =

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG pktbuf_dynamic(128): 0x381ac0c0

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: client_encoding = UTF8

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: DateStyle = ISO, MDY

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: integer_datetimes = on

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: IntervalStyle = postgres

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: is_superuser = on

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: server_encoding = UTF8

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: server_version = 9.6.24

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG make_room(0x381ac0c0, 15): realloc newlen=256

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: session_authorization = postgres

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: standard_conforming_strings = on

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 S: param: TimeZone = Etc/UTC

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a4190: incoming/postgres@172.21.0.3:5432 server login ok, start accepting queries

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 activate_client

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.353 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 logged in

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.366 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 Query rewrite not enabled in config (rewrite_query_py_module_file)

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.366 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 route_client_connection: Username => admin

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.366 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 route_client_connection: Query => SET extra_float_digits = 3

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.375 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: incoming/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 assigning client to connection pool for database <postgres1>

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.375 UTC [12] DEBUG C-0x3819c9b0: postgres1/admin@192.168.65.1:56405 pause_client

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@(bad-af):0 dns_callback: inet4: 172.21.0.3:5432

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 launching new connection to server

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 S: connect ok

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] LOG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 new connection to server (from 172.21.0.4:40538)

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.376 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 calling login_answer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 S: req md5-crypted psw

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 P: send md5 password

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: already progress

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] WARNING server login failed: FATAL password authentication failed for user "admin"

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] LOG S-0x381a43f0: postgres1/admin@172.21.0.3:5432 closing because: login failed (age=0s)

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.393 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 14 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-postgres1-1  | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-postgres1-1  | DETAIL:  Role "admin" does not exist.

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-postgres1-1  |        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 14 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.986 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.987 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:47.987 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 14 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.314 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.314 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.314 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 14 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 13 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:48.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 13 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.316 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.316 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.316 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 13 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 12 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.984 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.984 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:49.984 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 12 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.317 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.317 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.317 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 12 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 11 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:50.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 11 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 11 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.649 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 10 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:51.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 10 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.315 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 10 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.651 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.651 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.651 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 9 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.983 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.983 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:52.983 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 9 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.317 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.317 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.317 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 9 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 8 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.983 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.984 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:53.984 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 8 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.316 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.316 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.316 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 8 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.648 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 7 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.982 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:54.983 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 7 s

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:55.318 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection because not enough connections. number pools: 5, for: postgres1

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:55.318 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection loop: need to launch new connection because pool is not already a writer

pgbouncer-fast-switchover-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-01-04 11:30:55.318 UTC [12] DEBUG launch_new_connection: last failed, not launching new connection yet, still waiting 7 s
```